# Is it safe to leave my carbon bike in my stationary trainer for extended periods of time?

Tags: carbon, trainer

This time of year, I leave my race (carbon) bike on the trainer and when nice enough, just ride my rain/wet/commuter/cx bike.

I do replace the 'race' skewer with a steel skewer for trainer use.

Will it damage the carbon if I leave the bicycle clamped and ready to train on the trainer? Should I release the clamp every time I'm done training?

Comment: What kind of trainer is it? How is the bike attached to it? My guess is that damage is unlikely, but if it happens, it'll be from *riding* it on the trainer.

Comment: Cyclops Fluid 2 - Yeah, I imagine the stress of riding on the trainer is more than simply leaving it mounted.

Comment: Also see related question, [Can using a trainer damage my bicycle](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/4281/can-using-a-trainer-damage-my-bicycle). And, check with your bike manufacturer (in writing) as to whether trainers void your warranty.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image: cyclops fluid 2]

If this is the kind you have, then leaving the bike in there should make no difference whatsoever. This trainer clamps onto the rear axle, it doesn't even touch the frame. When you're off the bike, the frame doesn't have to do anything except support its own weight - there's no possible way it could get damaged.

You're probably *less* likely to damage the bike, since you won't be knocking it over.

Comment: Also, repeated unclamping/clamping is likely to be more damaging than just leaving it be.